# Server redirect issue in checkout sagepay magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, sagepay

I have installed the Sagepay payment method.

Getting below error after place order button is clicked.

> 5006: Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a redirection URL

I have checked the below link, but this doesn't solve the issue for me.

https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/error-codes?keyword=5006

Can anyone help me to solve the error, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a wildcard error message, it could mean a lot of things but here is a few common issues that might lead to this.

- A firewall is not letting Sage Pay POST information to Magento
- The site is in maintenance mode and restricted only to some ip addresses or any kind of restriction
- Site is protected with username and password not letting people viewing it unless they enter the correct information. On this one it can be bypassed if you only filter GET requests, more information here.
- An error in Magento is happening when the POST data reaches Sage Pay controller, before or after.
- SSL 3.0 is enabled, Sage Pay does not reach servers that are using SSL 3.0.

This information is taken from http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/sage-pay-common-problems

Answer (score 0):

> A firewall is not letting Sage Pay POST information to Magento

Incorrect URLs for payment success or failure in payment request can cause this issue too.

Basically what's happening is that sagepay is contacting the website and not getting a response in the expected format. This is after the payment panel or screen has shown and the transaction is authorised.

That is enough to cancel the transaction.

To put it in context with another provider it's like cancelling a PayPal transaction if the server doesn't respond to an IPN message.

I cant express in words how much of a pain this extra step has caused me over the years.

That said sage pay pi (sagepay.js) is a step in the right direction

Comment: Okay, What need to be done o resolve this one?

Comment: What extension have you used?

Comment: This is the extension we are using Customweb_SagePayCw

Comment: I don't know what one. Try their support first. They should know what endpoint to hit on your server to see if it is accessible to the outside world.